# Setting dynamic data in CKEditor 4 from Parent Component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

I want to initialize data in CKEditor 4 via props being passed from Parent. I am able to set default value into the editor but when the props changes its value, the editor's data doesnt get updated. It only takes the value being passed at the first render.

To understand this more easily I have created a sandbox which has 2 buttons. Clicking on it the props gets updated, but the value in the EDitor doesnt get updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ckeditor-4-forked-hmqv14

Thanks in Advance